# How can I get Jenkins to stop listening for remote connections?

Tags: ubuntu, hudson, jenkins

I have Jenkins sitting behind Nginx, with Nginx taking care of authentication, but Jenkins is still listening on port 8080 externally, so by accessing the box on port 8080 people can bypass Nginx.

How can I tell it to stop listening for remote connections and just accept connections locally?

It looks like it might be something to do with this ajp13ListenAddress param, but I can't figure out how to set that in the init.d script installed with Jenkins.

Thanks loads for any help!

Ludo.

(Looks like there's no Jenkins tag yet and I can't create it as I don't have rep)

Comment: Just added jenkins tag.

Comment: This is why I tend to deploy Hudson/Jenkins inside Tomcat..

Comment: Commenting, because I can't directly answer your question.  Have you considered mitigating by using iptables and/or tcpwrappers?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Debian

If you installed Jenkins from the Debian package, you can modify `/etc/default/jenkins` and add the following line somewhere:

```
HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

and then add `--httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST` to the JENKINS_ARGS so that it reads something like:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST"
```

### Ubuntu

If you installed Jenkins from the Ubuntu Oneiric (11.10) package, edit `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` and add `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1` to the `JENKINS_ARGS` line, so that it reads like:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=$JENKINS_RUN/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"
```

### RedHat/CentOS/Amazon Linux

If you installed Jenkins using YUM repository, modify `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and edit `JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS` to `JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1`

Comment: If like me you are in the third case but you are also using HTTPS, it's JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS that you want to set to 127.0.0.1

Comment: For RHEL/CentOS/Amazon Linux, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71507081/2035207). You should edit instead `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

Answer (score 2):

### Debian 11 from [Jenkins Package APT Repository](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu)

Edit configurations.

```bash
sudo systemctl edit jenkins
```

Add the following between two comment sections.

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1"
```

Then restart Jenkins.

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Check the actual command line used to start Jenkins.

```bash
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

Option `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1` is appended to the command line.

See also:

- [Jenkins Disable Access Control](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/access-control/disable/)
- [Installing Jenkins on Linux](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#weekly-release)
- [configuration - How do I override or configure systemd services? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services)